# Form with predefined values AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using `AngularJs` and  have inputs with predefined value from `ng-repeat`. I want resend those data value via `ng-click` function to treat data.

The problem the data is not submitted

```
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" class="form-group form-control" ng-value=s.prix required="required" ng-model="prix"  >
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" id='submit' ng-click="edit()" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

`s.prix` is a value of column in the table `prix (ng-repeat="s in produit")` if you know what i mean.

Comment: here's my controller

Comment: the function $scope.edit = function(){
        alert($scope.prix);
 };   here when the alert shows it says prix is undifined

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat instead as model

Like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-group form-control" required="required" ng-model="s.prix"  >
```

Then pass object in edit.

Try like this

```
ng-click="edit(s)"
```

JS

```
$scope.edit=function(s){
  console.log(s);
}
```

Comment: the think is i don't want the same value am updating the prix field  !! if you pass the object it will send you the default row without update §§

Answer (score 0):

**html:**

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

<label>Price</label>
<div ng-repeat="s in produit">
<input type="text" class="form-group form-control" required="required" ng-model="s.prix"  >
<button type="submit" id='submit' ng-click="edit(s)" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
</div>

</body>
```

**controller:**

```
myApp.controller('produitCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.produit = [{prix:'hello'}];

    $scope.edit=function(s){
          console.log(s);
        }

}]);
```